# working with the grid system in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, styling

I am relatively new to web development in general and am having a layout crisis: I have a *container-fluid* that has a *row* split into two *col-md-6*s. Within a col-md-6 I want to be able to position elements horizontally. As shown in my code/picture; I am trying to make a simple div that is 95% the height of the *button-group* and shows up next to it...however it is showing up below it and is very short (I want it to be as tall as the button group). What is the protocol for sizing/positioning elements next to each other in Bootstrap like this?

```
    <div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-6" style="background-color: lightcyan">
            <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-lg">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Quick Select</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Show in Depth</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Product</button>
            </div>
            <div id="prod_view">
                yo
                </div>
```

CSS:

```
    #prod_view{
background: lightcoral;
width: 69%;
height: 95%;
margin-left: 23%;
border: solid;
    }
```

What it looks like now:
[image: I want the "yo" box to be more square and to the right of the button group]

I want the "yo" box to be more rectangular and to the right of the button group.

Comment: You could always put another row in that column and break that up into two col-md-6 divs but you could also use flexbox there if you don't need to support IE10 or lower. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a flex layout that will do that. You can use the `justify-content` property to affect the horizontal alignment, and `align-items` will affect the vertical alignment. Here's a visual guide for flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.custom-row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
.custom-row > div:last-child {
  width: 69%;
}
#prod_view {
  height: 95%;
  background: lightcoral;
  border: solid;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-6 custom-row" style="background-color: lightcyan">
      <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-lg">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Quick Select</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Show in Depth</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Product</button>
      </div>
      <div>
        <div id="prod_view">
          yo
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks! Why do you have to put prod_view inside another div?

Comment: @MikeHawk np. By default the flex child of a flex parent will be 100% height. It's easier to leave that behavior alone, and just modify the children of the flex child if you want to change the height.

Comment: thanks and one more thing, how do you get rid of that space in between the button group and the flexparent?

Comment: @MikeHawk as mentioned in my comment with the answer, the `justify-content` property affects horizontal alignment/spacing. You can see the visual guide for different values you can use there.

Comment: @MikeHawk if you want them to be side-by-side, just remove that property entirely.

Comment: mmkay kkkthnxbb

Answer (score 0):

Another way is with a single flexbox class. Add it to the `row` and `col-md-6`:

```
.flex {
    display: flex;
}

<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row flex">
        <div class="col-md-6 flex" style="background-color: lightcyan">
            <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-group-lg">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Quick Select</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Show in Depth</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Delete Product</button>
            </div>
            <div id="prod_view">
                yo
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

http://www.codeply.com/go/wvCRJ0ufEB

In Bootstrap 4, [flexbox is default](http://www.codeply.com/go/UFVMW3TASM) so there is no need for the extra class.